# The system tries to cast my IntentService to an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I recently made some changes, and although I am unable to reproduce this crash on any of my devices after much testing, it is occurring somewhat frequently among users. It is different manufacturers, usually Android 6.0.1 but I have seen one 6.0.0 and 4.4.4. I don't have any idea what context it is occurring in.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxxxx/com.xxx.xxxxx.importfile.HardPathService}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.xxxxx.importfile.HardPathService cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3132)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5472)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:229)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1827)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.xxxxx.importfile.HardPathService cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1096)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5472)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:229)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1827)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The service is declared like this:

```
 <service
            android:name=".importfile.HardPathService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":pathservice"/>
```

I realize now that it does not need to be exported (it DOES need to be a separate process), but this is how it is declared when crashing.

The changes I made when it started crashing:

1. Change target and compile version SDK from 23 to 25.
2. The service is now started with a repurposed intent returned from `onActivityResult` which conveniently had data and clipdata already set. It used to start with a new'd intent. It looks like this:

   requestedIntent.setClass(getActivity(), HardPathService.class);
   getActivity().startService(requestedIntent);

I'm thinking it is somehow from using the intent again, but I don't know why it would sometimes fail, so I'd rather have an explanation before changing it.

Comment: Somewhere, you are calling `startActivity()` with an `Intent` that identifies this service.

Comment: @CommonsWare i looked through all occurrences of startActivity in project before posting, not anywhere that I can see.

Comment: @CommonsWare a Service declared like this would need an explicit Intent to start, correct?

Comment: "not anywhere that I can see" -- well, that's what your stack trace is showing. Note that the problem could also be in a `PendingIntent` that you passed to something else (`Notification`, `AlarmManager`, etc.), where it is the one doing the `startActivity()`. "a Service declared like this would need an explicit Intent to start, correct?" -- yes, as you have no `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I searched for class name I am definitely not starting it as an Activity, could system be trying to start it when its rebooting the process or something?

Comment: "could system be trying to start it when its rebooting the process" -- it would only do so if you had previously (successfully) used the `Intent` to start an activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare We see 'handleRelaunchActivity' I think that means it is rebooting it and only can be because of framework bug. I'm thinking my use of Intent used from onActivityResult somehow triggers it..

Comment: Well, at most, you are modifying your local copy of that `Intent`. If this is a process restart, the `Intent` that would be used would be one held outside your process (which, by definition, died). I suppose it's possible that the framework is making a copy of the local `Intent` after you have modified it, and it is that modified copy that's what's getting used. `Intent` has a standard copy constructor, so use that to make your own copy, then modify and use your own copy.

Comment: Post the complete code where you "repurpose" the `Intent` from `startActivityForResult()` please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply copying the data and clipData to a new intent made the crashes disappear completely. So, don't reuse your intents.

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), HardPathService.class);
startIntent.setData(requestedIntent.getData());
startIntent.setClipData(requestedIntent.getClipData());
getActivity().startService(startIntent);
```